# How does cudaLaunchKernel know the array size of "void **args"?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I know the size of array can be got with following code:

```
int a = 12;
float b = 12.0f;
char c = 'c';
void *param[] = { (void*)&a, (void*)&b, (void*)&c };

// the element size of param
size_t size = sizeof(param)/sizeof(void*);
```

But now, I want `param` be passed to a function named `TryToGetTheSize`, and get a size as the return value.

```
size_t TryToGetTheSize(void **array)
{
     // return the size of void* array
}

...

size_t size = TryToGetTheSize(param);
```

I've tried an idea from the implementation of `strlen`, which incrementally moves the `char*` pointer to next continuous memory space, and counting by check the value of current position is `'\0'` or not.

But that method does not work with `void**`, there is no way to check the validation of `void*` indicated address.

So, it seems impossible to know the size with only given the `void** array`, but when I lookup CUDA API, I found this:

```
cudaLaunchKernel(const void* func, dim3 gridDim, dim3 blockDim, void** args, size_t sharedMem, cudaStream_t stream)
```

In the CUDA, we usually use `<<<>>>` as kernel launching, but it's the same if we manually setup the arugments and call `cudaLaunchKernel` directly

In `cudaLaunchKerenl` API, I notice the fourth parameter `args` used as parameters of kernel function `func`, and there is no other parameters describe the size of `args`

So, I have two questions:

1) How does `cudaLaunchKernel` know the size of `void** args`?

2) If `cudaLaunchKernel` doesn't need to know the size of `void** args`, how does it work?

Here are my sample code that use `cudaLaunchKernel` instead of `<<<>>>` in kernel launching.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>

__global__
void saxpy(int n, float a, float *x, float *y)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < n) y[i] = a * x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
    int N = 1 << 20;
    float *hx, *hy, *dx, *dy;
    hx = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    hy = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc(&dx, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&dy, N * sizeof(float));

    for (int idx = 0; idx < N; idx++)
    {
        hx[idx] = 1.0f;
        hy[idx] = 2.0f;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(dx, hx, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dy, hy, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    unsigned int threads = 256;
    unsigned int blocks = (N + 255) / threads;

    float ratio = 2.0f;

    //saxpy<<<blocks, threads>>>(N, ratio, dx, dy);

    void *args[] = { &N, &ratio, &dx, &dy };
    cudaLaunchKernel((void*)saxpy, dim3(blocks), dim3(threads), args, 0, NULL);

    cudaMemcpy(hy, dy, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    float max_error = 0.0f;
    for (int jdx = 0; jdx < N; jdx++)
    {
        max_error = max(max_error, abs(hy[jdx] - 4.0f));
    }

    printf("Max Error: %f\n", max_error);

    cudaFree(dx);
    cudaFree(dy);
    free(hx);
    free(hy);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [related documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gb8f3dc3031b40da29d5f9a7139e52e15):

> The number of kernel parameters and their offsets and sizes do not
>   need to be specified as that information is retrieved directly from
>   the kernel's image.

Every CUDA device function has its argument list stored with the statically compiled function code. The API, therefore, knows exactly how many argument entries a call to `cudaLaunchKernel` requires. You will get a segfault or undefined behaviour if you supply too few to the launch call.